# Grab div text by class and create shortcode to display on search results page

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to grab some text inside of my WordPress pages that are inside the div with a class of "avia-textblock". I want to use this text to create a new excerpt using a shortcode to add to my search results page.

Here is my html:

`<div class="aria-textblock"><p>Some text here</p></div>`

Here is my code inside my functions.php file:

```
function get_new_excerpt(){
     $dom = new DOMDocument;
     $dom -> loadHTML( $data );
     $divs = $dom -> getElementsByTagName('div');

foreach ( $divs as $div )
{
    if ( $div -> hasAttribute('class') && strpos( $div -> getAttribute('class'), 'avia_textblock ' ) !== false )
    {
        return $div -> nodeValue;
    }
}
}
add_shortcode( 'new_excerpt', 'get_new_excerpt' );
```

How can I get my excerpt to show up? I am getting this error:
DOMDocument error on loadHTML() “Empty string supplied as input”?

Comment: scrapping your own site seems like an odd idea, there must be a better way to access your own content

Comment: You're probably better off saving `Some text here` as a custom field to the page, and then returning that with the shortcode instead of parsing it with `DOMDocument`

Comment: @Xhynk, I guess I don't know how to approach the problem. The website I'm working on has a huge number of pages, and they are not using the default content editor, or an excerpt. I need there to be an excerpt for my search results page. I figured if I can grab some text from the page, then create a shortcode, I could add them to my search results page. I don't want to have to edit thousands of pages.